# Sitecore's Publishing setting vs. a Custom field

Tags: best-practices, sitecore-api

I'm using Sitecore 8.2 - update 2.

Scenario:
I like to list all of the articles sorted by a `Publish Date`.

Which is the best practice/approach?

1. Sitecore's Publishing Setting: Use Sitecore's OOTB Publishing Setting. I can set the `from` field. In my rendering, I will sort the items based on `item.Publishing.PublishDate`.
2. Custom Field: Add a field name 'Publish Date' to the template. Set it as a Date field. After mapping the items to an object, in the `IEnumerable`, use this field as to Sort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For those scenario's I always use a custom field and the reason is rather simple: if your article gets an update (can be for something stupid like a typo) the ootb publish date will change but you probably don't want that effect in your sorting. Well, that's my experience - they (customers) mostly want the original publish date..

It's a choice between something automated and something manual. Involve the customer/editor in this decision:

- the automated way is less work - although it's not that much work to set "today" in a date field and you could even set it in the standard values
- the manual way gives them more flexibility (also had cases where the publishing date of the article was not the actual publish date they wanted to see.. )

So as I said, in my experience it always turned out in favor of the date field on the template

Comment: It won't change if you manually set the publishing from date. If you don't, it'll take on the updated date.

Comment: If you can get that explained to a content editor, I'm hiring you to do our trainings ;)

Comment: Updated the answer with a bit more reasons why I end up with a template field..

Comment: Love the second comment. Are you guys hiring? ;-)
Noted. You're right, the right approach is to get the content editors involved to see which one they favor.

Comment: We're using SXA and in our page list we went with the custom field to sort articles by date. Worked just as we expected.